# msbuild throwing error for added link for resource in c# project

Tags: c#, maven, msbuild

I want to create a common Version.cs which has copyright and assembly version infromation. I want same file to be refered by 2 projects using Add Link feature. So whenver there is new release I just want to make changes in Version.cs file. My both the prjected located in below location.
Below two projects are generated from

**Project 1**
C:\remote\local\Sources\myproj-template-archetype\target\test-classes\projects\snap_proj\project\snap_proj\MyLibrary_1

**Project 2**
C:\remote\local\Sources\myproj-template-archetype\target\test-classes\projects\snap_proj\project\snap_proj\MyLibrary_2

My Version.cs is located in C:\remote\local\Version.cs

Now when I try to build these project using mvn clean install. I am getting error for Version.cs. Error is

> [INFO]      [exec]   CSC : error CS1566: Error reading resource
>   'Com.org.snap_proj.MyLibrary_1.Com.org.snap_proj.MyLibrary_1.Version.cs'
>   -- 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\remote\local\Sources\myproj-template-archetype\target\test-classes\projects\snap_proj\project\snap_proj\MyLibrary_1\Com.org.snap_proj.MyLibrary_1\Version.cs'.'
>   [C:\remote\local\Sources\myproj-template-archetype\target\test-classes\projects\snap_proj\project\snap_proj\MyLibrary_1.csproj]

Comment: Are you sure you want to build C# with Maven?

Comment: Yes thats the requirment. There is template project from template project I need to generate project 1 and 2.

Comment: Could you post the pom.xml as well?

Comment: @JFMeier Thanks for the help. I was refering the resource which is outside the mentioned reference in pom.xml. I have included the file inside reference folder which was mentioned in pom.xml.